# Powershell - json File - Active Directory - add Attribut

Tags: json, powershell, active-directory

this is an extraction of my json File:

```
[
        {
        "UID":  "Name of UID OU",
        "Production":  "DistinguishedName of Production OU",
        "ProductionFolders":  [ 
                                "Name of Production Folder 1", 
                                "Name of Production Folder 2"
                              ],
        "ProductionFoldersDN":  [ 
                                  "DistinguishedName of Production Folder 1 ", 
                                  "DistinguishedName of Production Folder 2"

                                ],
        "ProductionSubfolders":  [
                                      "Name of ProductionSubfolder 1 ",
                                      "Name of ProductionSubfolder 2"
                                  ],
        "ProductionSubfoldersDN":  [
                                         "Distinguished Name of ProductionSubfolder 1",
                                         "DistinguishedName of Prodcution Subfolder 2"
                                   ]
        }
]
```

**If there is only the "Production" entry in the json file and no "ProductionFolders" or "ProductionSubfolders" entry**:
add "Test=UID" to the AD-Attribute "description" of the Active Directory OU (if it does not already exists)

**If there are also the "ProductionFolders" entries in the json file, but no "ProductionSubfolders" entries:**
only add "Test= name of the Production Folder" to the AD-Attribute "description" of every Production Folder OU (if it does not already exist)

**If there are "ProductionSubfolders" entries in the json file:**
only add "Test=name of the Production Subfolder" to the AD-Attribute "description" of every Production Subfolder OU (if it does not already exist)

My approach:

```
$json = Get-Content "C:\prod.json" |ConvertFrom-JSON

$onlyProd = $item.UID

$Folders = $item.ProdcutionFolders

$Subfolders = $item.ProductionSubfolders


foreach($item in $json) {

    
    if ($item.ProductionFolders -eq $null -and $item.ProductionSubfolders -eq $null) {   ###only Production entry exists 

        $Prod = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $item.Production -Properties description|Select-Object description
        if ($Prod.description -notlike "*Test*") {Set-ADObject -Identity $item.Production -Add @{description="Test=$onlyProd"}}
    }

    
    elseif ($item.ProductionSubfolders -ne $null) {    ###Production Subfolders entries exist 

        foreach (Entry in $item.ProductionSubfolders ???){
        $ProdSubFolders = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN -Properties description|Select-Object description
        if ($ProdSubFolders.description -notlike "*Test*") {Set-ADObject -Identity $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN -Add @{description="Test=$Subfolders"}}}
    }

    elseif ($item.ProductionFolders -ne $null -and $item.ProductionSubfolders -eq $null) {   ###only ProductionFolders entries exists 

        foreach (Entry in $item.ProductionFolders ????) {
        $ProdFolders = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $item.ProductionFoldersDN -Properties description|Select-Object description
        if ($ProdFolders.description -notlike "*Test*") {Set-ADObject -Identity $item.ProductionFoldersDN -Add @{description="Test=$Folders"}}}
    }

}
```

Can you please help me?

THANKS!!!

Comment: i dont understand the result waited, to clarify, could you give some examples of input json and result waited..

Comment: My main problem is that I do not know how to check if for example the key "Production" in the json File exists. Because that is not always the case.                           so i get the json File with $json = Get-Content $path | convertfrom-json .. and then I want to check the key "Production": foreach ($item in $json) { if (Get-Member -InputObject $item.Production) { Write-Host "The key production exists for this item in the json File"}  - does not work, how can I do that?

Comment: your syntax is not good, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to test if the key "Production" exists, you could do that:

```
foreach ($item in $json)
{
    if (Get-Member -inputobject $item -name "Production" -Membertype Properties)
    {
       "key production exists";
        $item.Production;
    }
    else
    {
       "key production doesnt exist";
    }

    if (Get-Member -inputobject $item -name 'ProductionSubfolders' -Membertype Properties)
    {   
       foreach ($item1 in $item.ProductionSubfolders)
       {
          $item1;
       }
    }
}
```

you could use this syntax for all keys you are searching...

if you want to iterate over list:

```
if (Get-Member -inputobject $item -name 'ProductionSubfolders' -Membertype Properties)
{   
    foreach ($item1 in $item.ProductionSubfolders)
    {
        $item1;
    }
    # if you want to use for loop with index for example
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt $item.ProductionSubfolders.Count; $i++)
    {
        $item.ProductionSubfolders[$i];
        $item.ProductionFoldersDN[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But I have another issue... if ,for example, the key "ProductionSubfolders" exists, I want to add an AD attribut for all Subfolders... but as the key "ProductionSubfolders" usually has more than one entries in the json File, I would need "foreach"... How do I do that?

Comment: I've tried: 
`
foreach ($item in $json)
{
      if (Get-Member -inputobject $item -name "ProductionSubfolders" -Membertype 
      Properties) {
            foreach ($i in $item.ProductionSubfolders) {
                $p= Get-AdOrganizationalUnit $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN -Properties 
               description|Select-Object description                                                                                 
               if ($p.description -notlike "*test*") {Set-ADObject -Identity $item.ProductionFoldersDN .Add @{description ="Test"}}} '

Comment: The values of ProductionSubfolders are names of Organizational Units in the AD. The values of ProductionSubfoldersDN are the associated DistinguishedNames of the Organizational Units. For example the values of ProductionSubfolders are "Office" and "Production" and the values of ProductionSubfoldersDN are "OU=Office, OU=x, DC=x,DC=x" and "OU=Production, OU=x, DC=x, DC=x"... and I want to add an attribut in the Active Directory for the Organizational Units "Office" and "Production"

Comment: So the result in this case would be that the attribute called "description" in the Active Directory of the OUs "Office" and "Production" gets the value "Test or whatever"

Comment: Thanks a  lot! But I also need the associated ProductionSubfoldersDN - so "foreach ($item1 in $item.ProductionSubfolder) {Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN}. Unfortunately that does not work. The first value in ProductionSubfolders belongs to the first value in ProductionSubfoldersDN ... do you know what I mean?

Comment: Do I need an array and call it with index or something like this? I really do not have a clue

Comment: ok i give you sample of for loop with index..

Comment: Thanks! But I do not really know how to combine ProductionSubfolder and ProductionSubfolderDN ... I will start a new question with better and less description and mark this as solved! As  you really helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: glad to help you, so yes open a new question with sample file input and result waited, its better than explanations